# Inconsistency between from_avro and from_json function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-avro

Spark `from_avro` function does not allow schema to use dataframe column but takes a String schema:

```
def from_avro(col: Column, jsonFormatSchema: String): Column
```

This makes it impossible to deserialize rows of Avro records with different schema since only one schema string can be pass externally.

Here is what I would expect:

```
def from_avro(col: Column, jsonFormatSchema: Column): Column
```

Code example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_avro

val avroSchema1 = """{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"str1","type":"string"},{"name":"str2","type":"string"}]}""" 

val avroSchema2 = """{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"str1","type":"string"},{"name":"str2","type":"string"}]}"""


val df = Seq(
  (Array[Byte](10, 97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 49, 0), avroSchema1),
  (Array[Byte](10, 97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 50, 0), avroSchema2)
).toDF("binaryData", "schema")


val parsed = df.select(from_avro($"binaryData", $"schema").as("parsedData"))


parsed.show()

// Output:
// +------------+
// |  parsedData|
// +------------+
// |[apple1, 1.0]|
// |[apple2, 2.0]|
// +------------+
```

Any suggestion on how to use different schemas to pass different avro records in spark dataframe ?

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, `df.select(udf(from_avro($"binaryData", _: String)).apply($"schema").as("parsedData"))` can't work (compiles but throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported` at runtime). 2. `from_avro` is [defined](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/connector/avro/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/avro/functions.scala#L41-L65) via [`AvroDataToCatalyst`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/connector/avro/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/avro/AvroDataToCatalyst.scala#L33-L36).

Comment: Maybe similarly the following class can be defined: `case class BinaryAvroDataToCatalyst(child: Expression, jsonFormatSchema: Expression, options: Map[String, String]) extends BinaryExpression with ExpectsInputTypes { override def inputTypes: Seq[AbstractDataType] = Seq(BinaryType, StringType) ...`

Comment: 3. Or maybe `df.select` can be done twice. Firstly, `df.select($"schema").as[String].collect()`. Secondly, `df.select(from_avro($"binaryData"...` based on the result of the first `df.select`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin - I'm using option #3 now which requires me to SEQUENTIALLY process foreach avro schema. I introduced a Future to perform the action in a separate threads in order to remove the sequential processing.

Comment: Great! Maybe you could submit your own answer to your question providing some details?